# Taking part of a char array and putting it into a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

So, I currently have a char array of 2000 chars. I will have 24 or less chars in the middle of this array that I need turned into a string. I have no ideas how to do this after many logic combinations and Google searches. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you written any code yet on this or just trying to get idea.?

Comment: A lot of code and a lot of failures that I deleted. I can recreate some of what I deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String provides a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(int[],%20int,%20int)) designed specifically for this task:

```
char[] bigData = ...
int startIndex = ...
int len = ...
String res = new String(bigData, startIndex, length);
```

`startIndex` represents the position in the array of characters where your string should begin; `len` represents the number of characters to take.

Answer (score 2):

try  this constructor

```
String(char[] value, int offset, int count)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is meant o be plugged into the offset and count

Comment: If char[]  a = {'a','b','c','d'} then new String(a,1,2) will make "bc"